# Accessing large amounts of memory from compute shader?

Tags: opengl, glsl, compute-shader

I need to access large amounts of data from a GLSL compute shader (read and write).

For reference, I work with an nvidia A6000 gpu with 50GB of memory, the driver is up to date.

Here is what I've tried so far:

1. Using a SSBO: `glBufferData()` can allocate arbitrarily large buffers but the shader will only be able to access 2GB of memory (according to my tests).
2. Using a texture: `glTextureStorage3D()` can allocate very large textures but the shader will only be able to access 4GB of memory (according to my tests).
3. Using multiple textures: I break the data in multiple bindless 3D textures (`GL_ARB_bindless_texture` extension) that work like pages of memory.  I store the texture handles in a UBO.  It effectively does what I want but there are several downsides:

   - The texture/image handle pairs take space in the UBO, which could be needed by something else.
   - The textures are not accessed in a uniform control flow: two invocations of the same subgroup can fetch data in different pages.  This is allowed on Nvidia gpus with the `GL_NV_gpu_shader5` extension, but I could not find a similar extension on AMD.
4. Using `NV_shader_buffer_load` and `NV_shader_buffer_store` to get a pointer to gpu memory.  I haven't tested this method yet, but I suspect it could be more efficient than solution 3 since there is no need to dereference the texture/image handles which introduce an indirection.

Thus, I would like to know: Would solution 4 work for my use case?  Is there a better/faster way?  Is there a cross-platform way?

Comment: "*according to my tests*" You keep saying this, but the implementation does tell you what these limitations are. You don't need to run "tests"; you can just query the right implementation-defined values.

Comment: "*The texture/image handle pairs take space in the ubo, which could be needed by something else.*" Even if you had 100 of them, that would only be about 3KB.

Comment: @NicolBolas well, sometimes. Other times the actual limits aren't what it says they are. This principle applies to all software: if it can be done wrong, someone probably did it wrong.

Comment: @user253751 The limits are tested by the Khronos conformance tests. GPU vendors can't, in general, get away with claiming higher limits than they actually support.

Comment: My GPU reports the following limits:
GL_MAX_SHADER_STORAGE_BLOCK_SIZE: 2147483647
GL_MAX_UNIFORM_BLOCK_SIZE: 65536
GL_MAX_3D_TEXTURE_SIZE: 16384
GL_MAX_ARRAY_TEXTURE_LAYERS: 2048
GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 32768
So you are right concerning ssbos, the limits are clearly defined. However, this is not the same for textures. These numbers are upper limits along one dimension, but it says nothing about the combined dimensions of a texture. I tried to write to a 2048² x 256 rgba array texture which works, but more than 256 layers stops working. Are these limitations defined anywhere ?